# Issues with android debug bridge commands

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-sdk-2.3, platform-tools

I have difficulties to run adb commands, they are not running at all!

for example `adb devices` or `adb connect deviceip:deviceport` and all commands of adb.

here is an example:
[image]

Also in Android Studio

[image: Android Studio Device list not working]

What could be the problem

My operating system is Windows 11

I try to erase all the Android Sdk, gradle files, and .android folder, also the IDE, but nothing

Comment: is adb path added to environment variables?

Comment: Check and kill other running `adb.exe` processes. E.g. via Windows taskmanager. Also check if TCP port 5037 is used on your system. This port is required by adb.

Comment: yes, adb path is added to the Path variable environnement, and TCP port 5037 is used by java.exe, it is normal?

Comment: No this is nor normal. adb is a program written in C/C++ and thus java.exe is not used by adb. Check what java process is blocking adb by looking at it's command-line.